# Sorting & Placing shared Google Drive documents into folders

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api

Is there a script/extension available to automatically sort Google Drive documents that are shared via email and place them into a specified folder created in Google Drive.  For example if John D shares the Morning Meeting Notes with me via email then I could automatically have that file saved into John D's folder in Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea from this post by [StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67730/automating-predictable-received-gmail-attachments).

So here is the user's needed:

Would it be possible to

> 1. Send an automatic received receipt exclusively to emails that send time-sheet type image or PDF attachments.
> 2. Label the Gmail with 1 or 2 separate labels like "time-sheets" and "downloaded"( read next part )
> 3. send the attachment to a specific google drive folder.

You have exactly same scenario.

Here are the answers:

For 1.

> You'll need to turn on the "Canned Responses" Gmail Lab. Create a
>   canned response with your response text ("Received").
>
> Then, adjust or create a filter:
>
> ```
> to:myEmail@gmail.com has:attachment .pdf
> ```
>
> That should pick up any PDF file that's sent to you. (You could get a
>   false match if someone sends some other sort of attachment and puts
>   the string ".pdf" somewhere in their message.)
>
> If you want to match on more file types, you can do something like
>
> ```
> .png OR .jpg OR .gif OR .tiff OR .jpeg OR .tiff
> ```
>
> For the action, choose "Send a canned response" and, obviously, choose
>   the canned response you created earlier.

For the 2nd question, here is the response:

> In order to label a message via filter with two separate labels,
>   you'll need to have two separate filters. Just copy the criteria for
>   one filter to the other. (If you're ambitious, you can export your
>   filters, edit the resulting XML, then re-import them.)

And for the last:

> You can easily do that with an IFTTT recipe. The Gmail channel lets
>   you trigger on a Gmail search and then you can use that to save to
>   Google Drive. [Here's a recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/99068-save-my-email-attachments-to-google-drive) that's similar to what you'd want
>   to do.

To get sample scripts, here is a documentation for [drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) and [gmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) and for further reading as well.